# Jquery PopUp Just One Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, bpopup

I am trying to resolve this.

In my page I have the Bpopup plugin. so here is my code:

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        speed: 650,
        transition: 'slideDown'
    });
});
</script>
```

**ELEMENT THAT SHOWS THE POPUP**

```
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
 <a class="b-close"><a/>

<p> hi </p>

</div>
```

What I want to do is to make that popup appear only once a day. I know it has something to do with cookies. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery approach**

```
$.cookie("popup_showed", 1, { expires : 1 });
```

and then get the value of the cookie to check if was already shown:

```
$.cookie("popup_showed");
```

See more at [Kazar's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458728/1827921) and [jQuery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

PS. Try not using the capslock - it makes your post less readable.

Comment: Thank you for the recomendation michal.. i have a question.. what is suppoused to be in "popup_showed" tag? i think there needs to be the Bpopup function? and how? :(

Comment: `popup_showed` is the name of the cookie that you're setting. The algorithm should look somewhat like this: in your popup-showing function you check if the cookie exists, and if it does - you check when was it created. If it was created `today`, then you're doing nothing (not showing the popup). If the cookie doesn't exist - you show the popup and set the cookie. And so it goes... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript cookies for this:

Click the W3Schools reference will help you

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp